# Error to emit socket: internal / bootstrap / pre_execution.js: 308

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:308
    get() {
       ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at get (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:308:8)
    at hasBinary (/home/spirit/Documents/ProjectsJS/ProjectBack/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:44:3)
```

Hello I am trying to issue my socket but I have this error, and I can not receive my socket in the back end below all the code I used

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  setInterval(() => Queue.searching() , 1000);
  sessionMap.set(socket.id,socket);
  //ADD PLAYER TO QUEUE
  socket.on('addPlayer-Queue', (result) => {
      const player = {
        id:result.id,
        socketid: socket.id,
        name: result.name,
        mmr: result.mmr,
        socket: socket
      }
      const nPlayer = new Player(player);
      Queue.addPlayer(nPlayer);  
      /*
      console.log(queue);
      console.log(sessionMap.all());*/
  //socket.emit('match', matches) 
  });


});
```

//

```
 searching = () =>  {
    const firstPlayer = this.getRandomPlayer();
    const secondPlayer = this.players.find(
      playerTwo =>
        playerTwo.mmr < this.calculateLessThanPercentage(firstPlayer) &&
        playerTwo.mmr > this.calculateGreaterThanPercentage(firstPlayer) &&
        playerTwo.id != firstPlayer.id
    );
    if(secondPlayer){
    const matchedPlayers = [firstPlayer, secondPlayer];
    this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
    Matches.configurePlayersForNewMatch(matchedPlayers);
    }
  }
```

//

```
  getMatchConfigurationFor = players => {
    console.log(sessionMap.all())
    if(players){
      const match = new Match(players);
      const result = {
        idMatch: match.id,
        playerOne: match.players[0],
        playerTwo:match.players[1]
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
  configurePlayersForNewMatch = (matchedPlayers) => {
    matchedPlayers.forEach(player =>
      sessionMap.get(player.socketId)
        .broadcast.to(player.socketId)
        .emit('match',
          this.getMatchConfigurationFor(matchedPlayers)));
  }
```

so what I admit the problem is in this code snippet:

```
matchedPlayers.forEach(player =>
  sessionMap.get(player.socketId)
    .broadcast.to(player.socketId)
    .emit('match',
      this.getMatchConfigurationFor(matchedPlayers)));
```

The session map is a mapping I made of my sockets saving key (socket id) and socket to send by emit later. on console log about my session.map this is console . log on my socket player https://pastebin.com/XHDXH9ih

Comment: I ran across the same error and after giving this a quick glance, I could suggest that maybe you're sending an object that is not serializeable or is too large. Check that you are not `socket.emit`-ing some object that is very large or circular.